# I accidentally voted down

Tags: discussion, support

instead up

Now trying to vote up, get message that I voted 16 hours ago and it's locked.

Should I wait 24 hours?

PS. 24 hours passed, but it's still locked.

When I'll be able to correct my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your vote is locked after a certain time(5 minutes). You cannot edit your vote unless the post you voted on is edited.

For further reference see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/271215) in meta.stackexchange which says,

> In general, once you have voted, you cannot change your vote. There
>   are two exceptions.
>
> - Exception one: you may change your vote a practically unlimited    number of times within a five minutes window from the first vote you
>     cast on that post. Note that after changing your vote ~60 times, it
>     will also be locked in.
> - Exception two: you may change your vote after every time the post is    edited. A new window starts with the first vote you cast after
>     each    edit.

**Reference** - [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes)

Also on a further note please use [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) for such questions about Stack Exchange rules, etc...

Comment: so no way to change vote?

Comment: @Alex Yes, there is no way.

Comment: @Alex, No, you can change the vote if the post is edited

Comment: yes, @Rowland, but I don't see reason why it can be edited